# (efficiently generated) coverage of a N-sphere

Tags: geometry

Fix parameters $n$ and $k$.  I would like to evenly cover the surface of the unit $n$-sphere with $k$ points $x_1,\dots,x_k$ in the following sense: I want to minimize the angle $\alpha$ s.t. for any vector $y$ there exists some $x_k$ which makes an angle at most $\alpha$ with $y$. (We can equivalently--and I care about this case too--ask for the minimal $k$ given $n, \alpha$.)

I believe this is equivalent to the optimal cover by spherical caps of a given size, which I believe is an open problem.  But I don't need a globally optimal solution, just a reasonably good one; however, I do need my solution to be effectively computable. More precisely, given $i,j$ I need to be able to compute the $j$th component of $x_i$ in time polynomial in the *logarithm* of $n,k$: i.e. a $P$-time turing machine given the binary representations.

Is there some well known even-ish covering that's easily computed for an arbitrary $n,k$? Given an arbitrarily small constant $\alpha$, what must $k$ be in terms of $n$? (What about even smaller angles--say, $\alpha = \frac{1}{n}$?)  Is this well-studied?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one suggestion. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, start with an icosahedron
inscribed in a unit-radius sphere,
and then tesselate each triangle as needed to reach your $k$,
projecting the new vertices onto the circumscribed sphere
(by normalizing their coordinates).
So you get a version of a geodesic dome:

---

[image: GeodesicDome5]

          

<sup>Graphics produced in Mathematica: `Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 5]`.</sup>

---

In $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d>3$, start with the vertices of the [cross-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope), and
perform a similar refinement of its facets to create new vertices projected
onto the circumscribing sphere, until you reach your $k$.
The vectors to these vertices are even-ishly distributed.

(In $\mathbb{R}^4$ you could start with the $600$-cell, but that only exists in 4D.)